# Spring data DBRef lazy loading with REST - 500 server error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data with MongoDB.

I have the following object:

```
@Document(collection = "Notification")
public class Notification {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef (lazy=true)
    private User sender;
}
```

When I try to return this object using the following method, I receive a `500 error` in my browser console and I can't see any data.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contactNotifications", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Notification> getContactNotifications() {
    List<Notification> notifications = notificationService.findByUser(user.getId());
    return notifications;
}
```

However, if I remove the `lazy=true`, it does appear to work.

How can I fix this while using `lazy=true`?

Comment: I think [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1029) is exactly your issue, so unfortunately no (other) solution yet.

Comment: Uggh yuck, that is pretty unfortunate. I'll keep it as eager now then I guess. Thanks for your comment, if you post that as answer  I'll approve your answer (when I wake up tomorrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set lazy to false so it would load all entities(notifications) associated with your entity (user) at load time. this would happen because it fetches data by using a select query to bring the user you requested then getting the notifications associated with it by another query which is skipped in when lazy is true, so you have to either set lazy to false or set fetch mode to "join" so it would bring the associated entities.

this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies?_sscc=t) might help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1029) is exactly your issue, so unfortunately no (other) solution *yet* than to eagerly load.